dns resolution not updating on changes
I have a database set to connect to a host, say, example.test.com. That domain is configured through AWS Route 53 as a failover configuration such that when the health check is positive it points to IP healthy.example.test.com but when it fails, it points to fallback.example.test.com.
Everything about the system is working as desired, the only issue is getting pgbouncer to recognize and propagate the new DNS setting when it changes. What needs to happen is that all existing connections are re-established and, along with new connections, pointed to the new DNS setting.
So far the only way I've been able to show that actually works (i.e. by testing) is to issue a KILL [db]; RESUME [db]. The problem with that is all of the clients that were connected get errors because of the KILL. The ideal scenario would be that clients are unaware of the change except for an bit of extra wait time.
I would hope that there is a more valid way of doing this. Am I missing something?
